# 2 forms to 1 Database Row

Tags: php, forms

On the one page (default_page) I created a form like this:

```
<form action="next_page/" method="post" id="add_this">
        <tr><th><label for="company_nip">NIP:</label></th>
        <td><input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'  name="company_nip" id="company_nip" class="regular-text" required placeholder="NIP" maxlength="10"></input></td></tr>
 <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="Send" /> </form>
```

On the other page (next_page/) my  next form look like this:

```
<form action="#v_form" method="post" id="add_this">

        <tr><th><label for="activation_code">Enter activation code:</label></th>
        <td><input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'  name="activation_code" id="activation_code" class="regular-text" required maxlength="10"></input></td></tr>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_formm" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Now I would like to data from both forms were sent to one row in database.
I know how to send only from one (code in next_page/):

```
if ( isset( $_POST["submit_form"] ) && $_POST["company_nip"] && != "" ) {
        $table = $wpdb->prefix."test";
        $company_nip = strip_tags($_POST["company_nip"], "");

        $wpdb->insert( 
            $table, 
            array( 
                'company_nip' => $company_nip
            )
        );

    echo '<div id="message_position_capreg"><p class="error_form"><font color="green">Success!</font></p></div>';
    }
```

How to modify that took also the value of $ _POST ("activation_code") and sent it along with that form for one record in db.
Column name for activacion_code is activaction

Comment: You can use session to store the posted data in first form. You can retrieve all data in next page.

Comment: ya, I know that,  but now, how to add that saved data from previous form to the database together with current form ( $ _POST ("activation_code") ).

Comment: use hidden input on second form that store the ones that come from 1st post ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new hidden field and put your data from first form in it. Which will be automatically passed along with the second form.